# Failed to deploy web package to App Service on Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Since Friday the 22nd of November, I have an issue to deploy updates on my WebApp. Only the code was updated, the release definition is the same since many months.

Here are the logs:

> 2019-11-22T21:33:50.1660947Z ##[section]Starting: XXXX API Deploy
> 2019-11-22T21:33:50.1779651Z
> ============================================================================== 2019-11-22T21:33:50.1779752Z Task         : Azure App Service deploy
> 2019-11-22T21:33:50.1779839Z Description  : Deploy to Azure App
> Service a web, mobile, or API app using Docker, Java, .NET, .NET Core,
> Node.js, PHP, Python, or Ruby 2019-11-22T21:33:50.1779907Z Version
> : 4.157.4 2019-11-22T21:33:50.1779976Z Author       : Microsoft
> Corporation 2019-11-22T21:33:50.1780041Z Help         :
> https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment
> 2019-11-22T21:33:50.1780145Z
> ============================================================================== 2019-11-22T21:33:50.8476296Z Got service connection details for Azure
> App Service:'XXXX-webapp-test'
> 2019-11-22T21:33:56.3772449Z Updating App Service Application
> settings. Data: {"WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE":"1"}
> 2019-11-22T21:33:56.8621554Z Updated App Service Application settings
> and Kudu Application settings. 2019-11-22T21:34:11.8877330Z Package
> deployment using ZIP Deploy initiated. 2019-11-22T22:44:42.6873709Z
>
> ### [error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service. 2019-11-22T22:44:42.6884687Z ##[error]Error: Error: Failed to deploy
>
> web package to App Service. Error: Request timeout:
> /api/zipdeploy?deployer=VSTS&message=%7B%22type%22%3A%22deployment%22%2C%22commitId%22%3A%222509aae88d82fbff1a5b4567e66d506ab75d5eb7%22%2C%22buildId%22%3A%221746%22%2C%22releaseId%22%3A%22142%22%2C%22buildNumber%22%3A%221746%22%2C%22releaseName%22%3A%22Release-83%22%2C%22repoProvider%22%3A%22TfsGit%22%2C%22repoName%22%3A%22XXXX-ServerV2%22%2C%22collectionUrl%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2FXXXX.visualstudio.com%2F%22%2C%22teamProject%22%3A%22fa101fe3-6537-4d7f-b39d-9825dde859d2%22%2C%22buildProjectUrl%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2FXXXX.visualstudio.com%2Ffa101fe3-6537-4d7f-b39d-9825dde859d2%22%2C%22repositoryUrl%22%3A%22%22%2C%22branch%22%3A%22Refactoring%22%2C%22teamProjectName%22%3A%22XXXX%22%2C%22slotName%22%3A%22production%22%7D
> 2019-11-22T22:44:44.0075802Z Successfully added release annotation to
> the Application Insight : XXXX-webapp-test
> 2019-11-22T22:44:44.2965245Z App Service Application URL:
> http://XXXX-webapp-test.azurewebsites.net
> 2019-11-22T22:50:48.0793152Z ##[section]Finishing: XXXX API Deploy

Did you notice something too? Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Does this happen continuously or occasionally? What about cancel and re-deploy again? Recently, we got several tickets like this issue. Recommend you raise ticket [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=21) which we could involve our product group into this issue investigation.

Comment: It's like 95% of the time, What I do to have a success is to create 5 releases and wait 1h to 5h hoping that one of the 5 works ...

Comment: Pity for this inconvenience. I think this would also need to involve Azure team to investigate whether it is also affect by them. Not very sure this because I haven't check from our backend to see your deploy detailed log. Do you mind raise ticket in [Develop community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=21)? I could not involve our product group into this loop because SO is a public forum, and it's not security for you to share some private org messages but necessary for our check.

Answer (score 10):

Thanks to Sergey Nosov on the MS forum:

> In the Function App, go to the "Deployment Center" blade, and click on
> the "Disconnect" button on top.
>
> After that re-run the release pipeline.

Worked for me....

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/382358/when-deploy-functionapp-to-slot-gt-error-package-d.html

Answer (score 4):

Check that there is a variable 'WEBSITE_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM' set in Application settings of Azure App Service.

If it does not exist add it. Make sure that it is set to true.

After that restart the App Service. Wait 20 seconds, then redeploy your application.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I already did it last Friday, but It doesnt work. Could it be possible that because of a long running webjob, the Deployment failed to deploy because a process is running and cannot be stopped?

Comment: If a running process is blocking at restart that could explain it. The simplest way may be to delete an recreate the app service.

Comment: I can't do that, the app is running and many users depend on it.

Comment: @CedricArnould You could use a load balancer (there are various Azure ones, or you could use a 3rd party one like Cloudflare. That should be a seamless transition. The you can create a 2nd appservice. Deploy to that. Then you can take down the old service, or set it up as part of an HA "BlueGreen" deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, for me, it was the Node.js version in my Azure Web app environment variables.

`WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` needed to be updated. Went from `6.9.1` to `8.5.3`.